# Firebase Notification Line break

Tags: android, json, firebase, notifications

Can I know how to put a new line or line break in Firebase Notification body parameter?
The notification from the phone shown as:

```
 Title: Title 1 Author: Author 1
```

What I expected was:

```
Title: Title 1 
Author: Author 1
```

Any clue on this? Below is the code, I have tried with \n \n \n\r, but they are not working at all.

```
JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
    body.put("body", "Title: Title 1\n"
                        + "Author: Author 1");
```